# How to use my smartphone headset on my computer?

Tags: audio, microphone, headset, headphone-jack

I recently bought a new laptop, an Acer VN7-791G-79TX. There is only one jack port for both headphones and microphone. I would like to use the headset that I use on my smartphone with my new laptop. The headset is an Urbanears Plattan, with a single jack for microphone and headphones too.

When I connect my headset, the laptop asks me what type of device I just connected. So I can choose : microphone, headset, headphones, speaker,... The problem is that my laptop can't use my headset microphone. I don't see it as a microphone in the control pannel, I tried defining it as a headset and then as a microphone.

Do you think it is possible to use it on my laptop? Also, there is a button on my headset to pick up the phone when I use it on my smartphone. Thankyou so much to the ones who will try to help me, the final aim is to use my headset on skype. Have a nice day! :)

My laptop right-side ports:

[image]

EDIT : After connecting it, if I define my headset as a LINE IN (which is the last option) I can see it in the recording part of the Sound program, as shown by DrZoo. But there is no point doing this because it is just a microphone.

Comment: When you plug the headset into the PC, does it work correctly for the speaker part?

Comment: Yes it does. And thankyou to The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like for the edit , I didn't have enough reputation.

Comment: Yes, my old eyes saw another port (icon) on the small picture :-}

Comment: If I read the symbol next to jack right, it's for headphone only. Doesn't that laptop have a builtin microphone?

Comment: @ott-- Look more closely, it is not a simple headphones port, it is a headset port. This is why there is a window appearing each time I connect something in this port, permitting me to choose how to use this jack port. Also, there is a builtin microphone but it is not really good, and too close from the keyboard.

Comment: This might be a fake jack. Can you open the notebook and check if it really has 4 connectors?

Comment: No I can't, I don't want to void the warranty. But I am sure it is a real microphone/headphones port as the constructor says.

Comment: Have you tried setting it as the "default communications device" in the audio device settings?

Answer (score 1):

Check in the *Sound* program and see if the microphone or headset is listed under the recording tab. If it is and does not have the green check mark by it, right click on it and choose to set it as the default device. It's probably choosing your laptop microphone over the handset microphone. Below is two images of what I'm describing. The red bar is just used to separate showing they are two different boxes.

**NOTE:** In Skype, you also have the ability to choose which microphone you want to use, assuming the computer is detecting more than one. You should try a test call on Skype and see if you can find out if it's recognizing the microphone on the handset.  [image]

Comment: Thankyou for your answer but as I said I don't see the microphone in the control pannel (I mean in the sound program). Therefore Skype doesn't recognize it.

Comment: @Sergie gotcha. I didn't quite know what you meant by `Control Panel` so I posted it.